# gulp-connect root as array

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

In the gulp-connect documentation, it says options.root can be an array or string.

I have a build directory that I would like to serve as my root, but I also have a (separate) sources directory that all of my source maps point to. Would I be able to leverage this options.root array syntax to allow me to serve both directories?

I have tried

```
root: ['build', 'sources']
```

but this results in only `build` being accessible through the server. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Possibly - do you have any more code that would be important here?  What are you calling from the sources folder that's not accessible? Docs seem pretty clear that you can use multiple roots, with a simple example. Something else must be in play.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does work, yet the root page displays in the index page only the first root.

What I did is create directory a with a simple index.html file which had in it:

```
<script src="b.js"></script>
```

then in directory b I put b.js with a single line:

```
alert("you found me!!!")
```

I started the following gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  connect.server({
    root: ['a', 'b'],
    port: 8080,
    livereload: true
  });
});
```

and loaded localhost:8080/index.html and ... the alert popped up